# CSS - not center aligning image properly

Tags: html, css

i am having trouble center aligning images.
The images should stay in center never mind what size your screen is. 
the problem is that the images are only center aligned until a specific size. my screen is quite small so they're perfectly centered, but when i go down to %75 the images are already not center aligned wich makes everything ugly.
i'm going to save you from spamming my code here, so just view the source of [this page.](http://minecraft.goldencreate.com/avatar.php)

Thank you for reading :)

Comment: take some time to review everyone's input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're wrapping the images in a `span8 offset2` div, which isn't designed for keeping them centered, but for keeping the element at a set width/left-offset.

Trying setting that parent div like so:

`#showcase .row-fluid > div { margin: 0 auto; width: 612px }`

Comment: that just makes all the images go to the side :I

Comment: Can you JSFiddle that to me please?

Comment: It would be hard to throw the full page in there. All you have to do is remove both the `span8` and `offset2` classes from the div containing the images, then use the css I gave you to control the width margins of it.

Comment: that's pretty much all i did, i'll try again, but as of now, look how the page looks :I

Comment: Well iv'e done what you told me to do but now when you minimize the screen too much one image still overflows :I

Comment: I refreshed your examples page and as I narrow my browser window, the images vanish once the page is too narrow. I'm not seeing any overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is pretty close already, since your `.head` divs are already inline-blocked, and your `#header` is `text-align: center`. What you'll want to do is remove the `offset2`, and change the `span8` to a `span12` so it encompasses the entire width.

Answer (score -1):

The `div` holding the images needs to have

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

and the image blocks need to have:

```
float: none;
display: inline-block;
```

Comment: Inline block is highly inconsistent across browsers, especially when dealing with whitespace. Floats don't need to be used or cleared either.

Comment: I put the `float: none` because he sets `float: left` like 80 times in his code when he doesn't need it.  And as for `inline-block`, I'm not sure what makes you think it's inconsistent across browsers: http://caniuse.com/inline-block but honestly I would just as soon tell him to change the `<div>` holding the `<img>` to a `<span>` or just not wrap it at all.

Comment: inline-block is consistent among recent browsers, but can be a pain to deal with because of the whitespace problems. That's less of an issue now with the `font: 0` tricks, but having to employ tricks is not a favorite thing of mine to do.

Comment: gotcha I haven't ran into that yet but I'm starting to research it now thanks

Comment: it's really lame, lol. Whitespace in the html can be rendered as actual spaces between elements in the layout. Like a padding that you never set

Answer (score -1):

I have seen this in your CSS and HTML code, if you remove it(CSS only) will stay in center.

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="span8 offset2">

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
Before
.offset2:first-child {
    margin-left: 17.094%;
}
After
.offset2:first-child {
   /* margin-left: 17.094%;*/
}
```

Comment: that looks like bootstrap code, and changing how the offset classes behave will cause further trouble in the future. neither classes are needed in this case